# vim removing xml tags

Tags: regex, vim, sed

I have a one liner in vim which I regularly use for find and replace.

I now want to use it to remove  tags - something like this but I looks like I need to escape the / I'm not sure what am I missing.

```
:%s~<Validator>*</Validator>~~g
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
:%s~<Validator>.*</Validator>~~g
```

Does the trick

Answer (score 2):

Just topple over that subject and had trouble to remove content over **multiple lines**. Here is what I come up with:

Input:

```xml
<Validator>
    <!-- hello world -->
</Validator>
```

Vim search replace:

```bash
%s~<Validator>\_.\{-}<\/Validator>~~g
```

The following vim wiki help me find the right syntax: https://vim.fandom.com/wiki/Search_across_multiple_lines

Answer (score -2):

use awk.

```
awk -vRS="</Validator>"  '{gsub(/<Validator>.*/,"") }1' file
```

The above removes from tag to tag, even if they span multiple lines.

Comment: if sed is mentioned in the tag, i don't see why awk cannot be used.

Comment: can you use AWK within VIM in the same we I am using SED ??

Comment: @imerez: You're not using sed; you're using vim's builtin :s[ubstitute] command.